# Sharethis In-line buttons not appering on Pop-up in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal, sharethis

I am implementing In-line sharethis buttons in a bootstrap modal.

ShareThis button are working fine on a rendered page.

But, they are not appearing on modal.

When I inspect the modal code or change the height of the inspect window, ShareThis buttons appears on modal.

I think this happening because inspect window changes the layout of the page.

JS link included in header

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#product=custom-share-buttons"></script>
```

This is the code of modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="inviteFriendsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="inviteFriends" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog " id="primary-header-modal" role="document" style="margin: 8% auto; width: 670px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close alert-close-icon" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Invite Friends, get {{INVITE_EARNED_REWARD}} points</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body bg-grayf2f2f2">
        <div class="row margin0 text-center">
          <img src="{{ asset('images/inviteFriends.png') }}" height="100px" class="margin-bottom20">
          <p class="font18">SHARE YOUR CODE</p>
          <p><span class="font18 font-wt400" style="color: #1fbad6;">{{Session::get('invitationCode')}}</span></p>
          <p class="padd-bottom15">Your friends get {{INVITE_EARNED_REWARD}} points when they join and you get {{INVITE_EARNED_REWARD}} too, after their first interaction.</p>
          <div class="text-center">
            <div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons" data-description='{{ $stSummary }}' data-url='{{ $stUrl }}' data-message="{{trans('interviewerMessages.inviteFriendsStSummary')}}" data-short-url="{{ $stUrl }}"  data-title="{{ trans('messages.ogTitle') }}"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also, I have created a test url for more clarification:
[URL](https://anujpanelist.roundone.asia/panelists/test-view)

Please help me on this issue that sharethis buttons should appears on modal on beforehand.